# Stock candleStick chart in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, charts, candlestick-chart

I need to create Stock CandleStick chart from scratch, Because we have some complex customization about Buy, Sell and Hold signal. I have prepared all data now looking forward to see some sort of starting point, I know Object C well but not too much experience in iOS platform. Can someone refer me to a good site or library, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used core-plot in past projects. I think its pretty good. It even has several built in pre-sets for stock graphs.

http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/

Comment: Hi Alex Thank you so much, I will take a look of core plot. I have few questions, Does core plot offer exact Candle Stick chart like most of the Chart application does? If Candle Stick chart is there, Is it possible to set low,high,close and open data?

Comment: Yep. There is a candle stick chart and you should be able to set it with those data sets.

Comment: Okay Great :) I will try now.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for real-time stock charts, have a look at SciChart's [ios stock chart component](https://www.scichart.com/ios-stock-charts/).

This supports ObjectiveC, Swift2, Swift3 and Xamarin.

[image]

It has some great features for trading applications including ability to synchronize multiple chart panes, display latest price values on axis, support for Candlestick, Line, Mountain, Column and OHLC charts, zooming and panning, tooltips and the ability to overlay buy/sell markers via the Annotations API.

It is a commercial (paid) control but the team will work hard for your business!

If you have questions let me know. **As a disclosure**, I am the MD of SciChart and the tech lead on the projects.